# Не читает код

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, дорогие участники! 
У меня есть слайдер, и для кнопки есть файл h2_trigger_a.gif, он находиться в папке с файлом faq.tpl. Только вот она не отображается... Почему? Вот код

```
h2.acc_trigger {
    padding: 0; margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    background: url(h2_trigger_a.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 46px;   line-height: 46px;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы уж извините но код я не читал. Перешел по ссылке а у вас там **500 Internal Server Error**

Так что ошибка у Вас на backend'е и именно там Вам и нужно искать ответ на свой вопрос. Посмотрите логи. error.log если быть конкретнее. Там обязательно будет ответ.

P.S. Тег CSS здесь не причем...

Comment: Возможно, я что - то не понимаю, но у меня просто белая страница...

Comment: Да белая страница. Потому что выключен показ ошибок в php.ini или где-то в другом месте. А все ошибки пишутся в лог. То что у Вас 500ая ошибка можно убедится в консоли браузера.

Comment: Хорошо. Сейчас я уберу css код и Вы увидите, что сайт пойдет. Ответ напишите в комент.

Comment: Вижу, что работает. Однако не css таких ошибок не вызывает. Так же как и javascript. Очевидно что ошибка в php. 
Я не знаток Смарти но не нужно ли обернуть тег style в {literal} так же как вы это сделали с javacript'ом?

Comment: Ура!!!! Могу ли я как - то Вас поблагодарить материально?

Comment: Не нужно, спасибо.

Comment: Кстати вы могли бы меня отблагодарить например открытием нового вопроса. А на этом оставить "решено". Так как вы уже задали новый вопрос здесь же и лишили меня некоторых балов рейтинга...